# How to enable embedded language intellisense and autocomplete in vscode?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a use case where I have a language X, inside which I'm supporting HTML. Since, I'm associating the file extension as'.x' in VScode, I'm not getting autocomplete and attribute suggestions for my HTML inside X. How can this be solved.

The approaches I tried,

- Created an extension for language X. In the extension, I fetched the `vscode.html` and activated it in the activate method.

```
const htmlPluginId = 'vscode.html';

export const activate = () => {
  const htmlPlugin = vscode.extensions.getExtension(htmlPluginId);
  const ht = await htmlPlugin.activate();
}
```

This didn't work. I guess, there is no association for the HTML plugin to run for language X.

- Created language server and client where I used HTML language service to perform completion and other tasks. This works. But, I feel I'm repeating things which are already in `vscode-html-languageserver`.

```
import {getLanguageService} from 'vscode-html-languageservice';

let connection = createConnection();

let documents = new TextDocuments(TextDocument);
const htmlLanguageService = getLanguageService();

connection.onCompletion((textDocumentPosition) => {
  const document = documents.get(textDocumentPosition.textDocument.uri);
  const htmlDocument = htmlLanguageService.parseHTMLDocument(document!);
  if (htmlDocument.roots.length > 0) {
    return htmlLanguageService.doComplete(
        document!, textDocumentPosition.position, htmlDocument);
  }
});

documents.listen(connection);
connection.listen();
```

Is there another simple approach where I can use HTML and its VSCode features inside my language?

Comment: related extension API docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/embedded-languages